# Как передать переменную с одного компонента в другой? React

Tags: reactjs

```
export const GetInputValue = (props) => {

    const value = props.value;
    return (
        null
    );
};

export function Items(props) {

    const temp = [];

    const howMuchTimes = (times) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < times; i++) {
            temp.push(i)
        };
    };


    howMuchTimes(!!Здесь должно быть значение переменной value!!);

    return (
        <div className="items-list">
            {temp.map((e) => <Item key={Math.random() * 9999} itemStyle={{
                background: '#fff',
                width: '140px',
                height: `${Math.floor(Math.random() * (850 - 10) + 10)}px`,
                 margin: '0 .2rem'
            }} />)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

`GetInputValue` через рендер-пропсы получает состояние из другого компонента, `const value` - в этой переменной записано то состояние, и вопрос как передать его в компонент `Items`?

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1)[Подъём состояния](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

> Часто несколько компонентов должны отражать одни и те же изменяющиеся
>   данные. Мы рекомендуем поднимать общее состояние до ближайшего общего
>   предка.

2) [Контекст](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

> Контекст позволяет передавать данные через дерево компонентов без
>   необходимости передавать пропсы на промежуточных уровнях.

3) [Компоненты высшего порядка](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)

> Компонент высшего порядка (Higher-Order Component, HOC) — это один из
>   продвинутых способов для повторного использования логики. HOC не
>   являются частью API React, но часто применяются из-за композиционной
>   природы компонентов.